# How to use all colors in Illustrator? Remove out of gamut checking

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gamut

I just can't make pure blue (R=0,G=0,B=255) circle. It says "out of gamut warning". If I press "fix" or something, it makes color black but not blue.

I don't need this "service".

How to bother out such things as "gamuts" and that similar staff?

I want each object be the color I want, not somebody regard as "correct".

Comment: What is the document color mode? (File menu) It should be set to RGB.

Comment: Yes, it was CMYK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure the **Document Color Mode** is set to RGB if you wish to use RGB colors.

`File > Document Color Mode`